# Mysterious unrelated task_id being returned for celery workflow.

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celeryd, djcelery

I have a rather complex workflow (which is built dynamically) which looks something like this:

```
workflow= chain(
signature('workflow.tasks.start_workflow', kwargs= {}),
chord(
    [
        signature('workflow.tasks.group_task', kwargs= {}),
        signature('workflow.tasks.sample_task_2', kwargs= {}),
        signature('workflow.tasks.sample_task_10', kwargs= {})
    ],
    chain(
        signature('workflow.tasks.sample_task_3', kwargs= {}),
        chord(
            [
                signature('workflow.tasks.group_task', kwargs= {}),
                chain(
                    signature('workflow.tasks.sample_task_5', kwargs= {}),
                    signature('workflow.tasks.sample_task_6', kwargs= {}),
                ),
                chain(
                    signature('workflow.tasks.sample_task_7', kwargs= {}),
                    signature('workflow.tasks.sample_task_8', kwargs= {}),
                )
            ],
            chain(
                signature('workflow.tasks.sample_task_9', kwargs= {}),
                signature('workflow.tasks.end_workflow', kwargs= {})
            )
        )
    )
)
```

)

which celery then turns into this:

```
workflow.tasks.start_workflow() | celery.chain(
    [
        workflow.tasks.group_task(),
        workflow.tasks.sample_task_2(),
        workflow.tasks.sample_task_10()
    ],     
    tasks=(
        workflow.tasks.sample_task_3(),
        celery.chain(
            [
                workflow.tasks.group_task(),
                workflow.tasks.sample_task_5() | workflow.tasks.sample_task_6(),
                workflow.tasks.sample_task_7() | workflow.tasks.sample_task_8()
            ], tasks=(
                workflow.tasks.sample_task_9(),
                workflow.tasks.end_workflow()
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Note how the the tasks at the end of the chord's are pushed into the "tasks" header.  From what I've read these tasks are stored in the main tasks header and not are put on the queue until the chords header finishes executing.

When I try to display the task_id for the entire workflow (which I would expect to be one of the task_id's within the workflow).

```
workflow= workflow.apply_async()
print workflow.id
>> 1d538872-79af-4585-aef8-ebfc06cd0b5b
```

This task id I get is not stored in celery_taskmeta or celery_tasksetmeta.  It's not any task that gets executed within the workflow (see worker log below).  Any idea, what this task_id represents and if there is anyway I can link it to any of the executing task?

I'd like to be able to traverse through the results and display a state for each task in the workflow.  However, this task id I get back doesn't seem to relate to any of the tasks.  Below is the worker log and you'll see that task id printed above is no where to be found!  Any ideas? Thanks.

```
[2015-03-03 15:34:42,306: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workflow.tasks.start_workflow[45b54d46-56cc-4c46-a126-d38ab8e8a2e8]
[2015-03-03 15:34:42,334: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workflow.tasks.group_task[ccce5c5b-0946-499a-9879-613b79333419]
[2015-03-03 15:34:42,335: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workflow.tasks.sample_task_2[3262ad97-c8ea-4b26-9bdc-f3a95fd41cf4]
[2015-03-03 15:34:42,335: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workflow.tasks.sample_task_10[64286589-7665-4574-864a-69f3175ec281]
[2015-03-03 15:34:42,336: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: celery.chord_unlock[055938f3-5a4e-4c77-aa76-ab3399206c87] eta:[2015-03-03 15:34:43.335836+00:00]
[2015-03-03 15:34:42,363: INFO/MainProcess] Task workflow.tasks.start_workflow[45b54d46-56cc-4c46-a126-d38ab8e8a2e8] succeeded in 0.0562515768688s: None
[2015-03-03 15:34:42,391: INFO/MainProcess] Task workflow.tasks.group_task[ccce5c5b-0946-499a-9879-613b79333419] succeeded in 0.0555328750052s: True
[2015-03-03 15:34:43,402: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: celery.chord_unlock[055938f3-5a4e-4c77-aa76-ab3399206c87] eta:[2015-03-03 15:34:44.400298+00:00]
[2015-03-03 15:34:43,404: INFO/MainProcess] Task celery.chord_unlock[055938f3-5a4e-4c77-aa76-ab3399206c87] retry: Retry in 1s
[2015-03-03 15:34:45,323: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: celery.chord_unlock[055938f3-5a4e-4c77-aa76-ab3399206c87] eta:[2015-03-03 15:34:46.320054+00:00]
[2015-03-03 15:34:45,325: INFO/MainProcess] Task celery.chord_unlock[055938f3-5a4e-4c77-aa76-ab3399206c87] retry: Retry in 1s
[2015-03-03 15:34:47,299: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: celery.chord_unlock[055938f3-5a4e-4c77-aa76-ab3399206c87] eta:[2015-03-03 15:34:48.297891+00:00]
[2015-03-03 15:34:47,299: INFO/MainProcess] Task celery.chord_unlock[055938f3-5a4e-4c77-aa76-ab3399206c87] retry: Retry in 1s
[2015-03-03 15:34:47,390: INFO/MainProcess] Task workflow.tasks.sample_task_2[3262ad97-c8ea-4b26-9bdc-f3a95fd41cf4] succeeded in 5.05364968092s: True
[2015-03-03 15:34:47,392: INFO/MainProcess] Task workflow.tasks.sample_task_10[64286589-7665-4574-864a-69f3175ec281] succeeded in 5.05569092603s: True
[2015-03-03 15:34:48,426: INFO/MainProcess] Task celery.chord_unlock[055938f3-5a4e-4c77-aa76-ab3399206c87] succeeded in 0.0345057491213s: None
[2015-03-03 15:34:48,426: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workflow.tasks.sample_task_3[89e6b3a6-1595-48e3-801d-28b36aafb581]
[2015-03-03 15:34:53,483: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workflow.tasks.group_task[5e4f63b9-6968-4210-91f7-b89e939d1c9a]
[2015-03-03 15:34:53,484: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workflow.tasks.sample_task_5[fc10ce62-5701-4c75-987e-7dac7b17bab6]
[2015-03-03 15:34:53,484: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workflow.tasks.sample_task_7[9893dd87-844b-44a3-b5d8-bca086ee15ec]
[2015-03-03 15:34:53,485: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: celery.chord_unlock[018c1e9e-3b2e-4a4c-90ed-5265b01eb9fb] eta:[2015-03-03 15:34:54.484729+00:00]
[2015-03-03 15:34:53,490: INFO/MainProcess] Task workflow.tasks.sample_task_3[89e6b3a6-1595-48e3-801d-28b36aafb581] succeeded in 5.06310376804s: True
[2015-03-03 15:34:53,527: INFO/MainProcess] Task workflow.tasks.group_task[5e4f63b9-6968-4210-91f7-b89e939d1c9a] succeeded in 0.043258280959s: True
[2015-03-03 15:34:55,328: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: celery.chord_unlock[018c1e9e-3b2e-4a4c-90ed-5265b01eb9fb] eta:[2015-03-03 15:34:56.327396+00:00]
[2015-03-03 15:34:55,329: INFO/MainProcess] Task celery.chord_unlock[018c1e9e-3b2e-4a4c-90ed-5265b01eb9fb] retry: Retry in 1s
[2015-03-03 15:34:57,336: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: celery.chord_unlock[018c1e9e-3b2e-4a4c-90ed-5265b01eb9fb] eta:[2015-03-03 15:34:58.333722+00:00]
[2015-03-03 15:34:57,339: INFO/MainProcess] Task celery.chord_unlock[018c1e9e-3b2e-4a4c-90ed-5265b01eb9fb] retry: Retry in 1s
[2015-03-03 15:34:58,424: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: celery.chord_unlock[018c1e9e-3b2e-4a4c-90ed-5265b01eb9fb] eta:[2015-03-03 15:34:59.423050+00:00]
[2015-03-03 15:34:58,425: INFO/MainProcess] Task celery.chord_unlock[018c1e9e-3b2e-4a4c-90ed-5265b01eb9fb] retry: Retry in 1s
[2015-03-03 15:34:58,517: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workflow.tasks.sample_task_8[aff7d810-9989-4dfe-8cca-1032efcf4624]
[2015-03-03 15:34:58,521: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workflow.tasks.sample_task_6[b758014f-5837-4bed-9426-5c2e03af2c2f]
[2015-03-03 15:34:58,538: INFO/MainProcess] Task workflow.tasks.sample_task_7[9893dd87-844b-44a3-b5d8-bca086ee15ec] succeeded in 5.05185400695s: True
[2015-03-03 15:34:58,539: INFO/MainProcess] Task workflow.tasks.sample_task_5[fc10ce62-5701-4c75-987e-7dac7b17bab6] succeeded in 5.05522017297s: True
[2015-03-03 15:35:01,325: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: celery.chord_unlock[018c1e9e-3b2e-4a4c-90ed-5265b01eb9fb] eta:[2015-03-03 15:35:02.322996+00:00]
[2015-03-03 15:35:01,326: INFO/MainProcess] Task celery.chord_unlock[018c1e9e-3b2e-4a4c-90ed-5265b01eb9fb] retry: Retry in 1s
[2015-03-03 15:35:03,337: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: celery.chord_unlock[018c1e9e-3b2e-4a4c-90ed-5265b01eb9fb] eta:[2015-03-03 15:35:04.335374+00:00]
[2015-03-03 15:35:03,339: INFO/MainProcess] Task celery.chord_unlock[018c1e9e-3b2e-4a4c-90ed-5265b01eb9fb] retry: Retry in 1s
[2015-03-03 15:35:03,594: INFO/MainProcess] Task workflow.tasks.sample_task_6[b758014f-5837-4bed-9426-5c2e03af2c2f] succeeded in 5.0567153669s: True
[2015-03-03 15:35:03,595: INFO/MainProcess] Task workflow.tasks.sample_task_8[aff7d810-9989-4dfe-8cca-1032efcf4624] succeeded in 5.05580001394s: True
[2015-03-03 15:35:05,315: INFO/MainProcess] Task celery.chord_unlock[018c1e9e-3b2e-4a4c-90ed-5265b01eb9fb] succeeded in 0.0105995119084s: None
[2015-03-03 15:35:05,316: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workflow.tasks.sample_task_9[2492e5e0-d6df-402c-b5a5-ab15d99b42ad]
[2015-03-03 15:35:10,336: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: workflow.tasks.end_workflow[4a2c0a15-77c9-417e-bd21-8a7f1d248981]
[2015-03-03 15:35:10,357: INFO/MainProcess] Task workflow.tasks.sample_task_9[2492e5e0-d6df-402c-b5a5-ab15d99b42ad] succeeded in 5.04111725814s: True
[2015-03-03 15:35:10,374: INFO/MainProcess] Task workflow.tasks.end_workflow[4a2c0a15-77c9-417e-bd21-8a7f1d248981] succeeded in 0.0367547438946s: None
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember exactly where that identifier gets generated, but celery does generate task identifiers for internal use depending on what canvas primitives are used. The biggest problem I ran into was the chord_unlock tasks, which you have no control over.

This won't help you in the short term, but I created a patch a long time ago that allows you to pass a 'root_id' argument when creating a workflow that will then get propagated to all children tasks and can be used to link them all together like you describe. It will also include a 'parent_id' field to further assist with traversing/tracking workflows as well.

The idea was accepted, but the code hasn't landed in an official release yet. It is supposed to land in the next major release v3.2.0 and you can monitor it here: https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/1318